# C Unix Fuse fwrite "segmento violado" después de n ejecuciones

Tags: c, unix

Les comento la situación, tenemos un servidor y un cliente que trabajan con un sistema fuse, el servidor, cuando atiende la petición de escribir un archivo, después de una x cantidad de veces al azar, genera el error de segmento violado.
Adjunto código de la función write

```
int poke_write(int socket)
{
    char* path = calloc(100,sizeof(char));
    char* contenido;
    int tamanio;
    size_t sizedef; off_t offdef;

    if(ctrlErrorRecv(recv(socket,path,100,0),socket) != 0)
    {
        free(path);
        return -1;
    }
    if(ctrlErrorRecv(recv(socket,&tamanio,sizeof(int),0),socket) != 0)
    {
        free(path);
        return -1;
    }

    contenido = calloc(tamanio+2,sizeof(char));
    if(ctrlErrorRecv(recv(socket,contenido,tamanio+1,0),socket) != 0)
    {
        free(path);
        free(contenido);
        return -1;
    }

    if(ctrlErrorRecv(recv(socket,&sizedef,sizeof(size_t),0),socket) != 0)
    {
        free(path);
        free(contenido);
        return -1;
    }

    if(ctrlErrorRecv(recv(socket,&offdef,sizeof(off_t),0),socket) != 0)
    {
        free(path);
        free(contenido);
        return -1;
    }
    log_info(logger_osada,"%d.write: %s",socket,path);
    log_info(logger_osada,"%d.  Size: %d    Offset: %d",socket,sizedef,offdef);
    int offset = reconocerPath(path);
    if(offset != -1)
    {
        t_File_System FS = leerDataFS();
        if (dar_lugar_Archivo(&FS,path,sizedef + offdef,offset,socket) == 0)
        {
            int *bloques = recorrer_bloques_de(
                    FS.files_osada[offset].first_block,
                    FS.tabla_Asignaciones,
                    FS.header->fs_blocks);

            sizedef = guardar_en_archivo(bloquesALeer(bloques,offdef),
                        sizedef,offsetIndicado(offdef),contenido,
                        FS.header->fs_blocks-FS.header->data_blocks);
            FS.files_osada[offset].file_size = sizedef+offdef;
            if ( grabarFS(&FS)!= 0)
            {
                log_info(logger_osada,"%d.  NO SE PUDO GRABAR!!",socket);
                sizedef = -1;
            }
            else{
                log_info(logger_osada,"%d.  archivo escrito",socket);
            }
            free(bloques);
        }else{
            sizedef = -1;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexFileSystem);
    }
    else{
        sizedef = -1;
    }
    send(socket,&sizedef,sizeof(size_t),0);
    free(path); free(contenido);
    return 0;
}
```

Sé que la función está explotando al llamado de "guardar en archivo" que contiene 4 fwrite

```
size_t  guardar_en_archivo(int *bloques,
        size_t size,off_t offset, char *contenido,int inicio)
{
    size_t indice_bloque = 1;
    size_t contador_de_bytes_escritos;
    size_t escrito = 0;
    size_t proteccion = size;
    printf("Maximos Bloques: %d\n",bloques[cant_mas1]-1);
    FILE* archi;
    if((archi = fopen(archivoBin,"w+")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo de configuracion\n");
        log_error(logger, "No se pudo abrir el archivo de configuracion");
        fclose(archi);
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek(archi,((bloques[indice_bloque]+inicio) * block_size) + offset,SEEK_SET);

    if((proteccion + offset) > block_size)
    {
        contador_de_bytes_escritos = fwrite(contenido,sizeof(char),block_size - offset,archi);
        printf("Bloq %d, %d\n",bloques[indice_bloque],contador_de_bytes_escritos);
    }
    else{
        contador_de_bytes_escritos = fwrite(contenido,sizeof(char),proteccion,archi);
        printf("Resto %d, %d\n",bloques[indice_bloque],contador_de_bytes_escritos);
    }
    escrito = escrito + contador_de_bytes_escritos;
    printf("Escrito desde: %d, %d\n",bloques[indice_bloque],escrito);

    while (proteccion-escrito > 0)
    {
        indice_bloque ++;
        fseek   (archi,(bloques[indice_bloque]+inicio)*block_size,SEEK_SET);
        if((proteccion - escrito) > block_size)
        {
            contador_de_bytes_escritos = fwrite
                    (&(contenido[escrito]),sizeof(char),block_size,archi);

            if(contador_de_bytes_escritos != block_size){
                printf("ERROR en fwrite!!\n");
            }
            printf("> \n");
        }
        else{
            contador_de_bytes_escritos = fwrite
                    (&(contenido[escrito]),sizeof(char),proteccion - escrito,archi);
            if(contador_de_bytes_escritos !=proteccion - escrito){
                printf("ERROR en fwrite!!\n");
            }
            printf("=> \n");
        }
        printf("%d.\n",indice_bloque);
        escrito = escrito + contador_de_bytes_escritos;
        fflush (archi);
        printf("Bloque: %d, %d\n",bloques[indice_bloque],proteccion-escrito);
    }
    printf("Escrito hasta: %d, %d\n",bloques[indice_bloque],escrito);
    fclose(archi);
    return escrito;
}
```

Y para ser aún más específico, aunque puedo estar equivocándome, la violación de segmento se produce en al ejecutar esta línea de códigos, después de una cantidad random de veces

```
contador_de_bytes_escritos = fwrite(&(contenido[escrito]),sizeof(char),block_size,archi);
```

Por favor avisar si necesitan más datos o si la consulta es apropiada, no puedo encontrar el motivo al error.

Comment: ¿Esto se ejecuta en un entorno multi-hilo? ¿qué queda en el log al ocurrir el fallo?

Comment: ¿Sabes utilizar GDB? con esa herramienta deberías encontrar el problema sin mucho problema, y es no es muy difícil de aprender a usar.

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente podrían ocurrir una de las dos cosas sobre las variables protección y escrito:

1. Ocurre un desbordamiento (poco probable)
2. Se están cambiando los valores de alguna variable de alguna forma que se ignora, puede ser que cuando se reserva memoria, alguna reserva queda contigua a la de estar variables y por una mala gestión de la misma podría estarse alterando la variable.

Comment: Esto es, en realidad un comentario, no una respuesta. Con un poco de reputación, [podrás publicar tus propios comentarios](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por el momento estoy solicitando la intervención de un moderador para que convierta esta no-respuesta en un comentario y la borre.

Comment: Haga algo que aporte a la solución de la pregunta.

Comment: Y no puedo agregar comentarios al usuario, por la reputación, ya que recién inicié.

Comment: Claro AntJk, comprendo. La idea en StackOverflow (y es lo que más nos diferencia de los viejos sistemas de foros) es que el espacio de respuesta se destina exclusivamente a aquellos aportes que ofrecen una solución al problema. De esta manera se hace fácil distinguir lo que son respuestas, del ruido (y evitas navegar por 5 o 10 páginas de 20 _posts_ cada una, para tratar de encontrar la respuesta al problema, y que además está fraccionada en 4 o 5 _posts_ diferentes (esa es la otra, que acá tanto pregunta como respuesta se editan para perfeccionarse).

Comment: Entiendo que al principio, sin embargo, es difícil. En lo personal no comparto del todo que el [privilegio](/help/privileges) de [comentar en todas partes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) esté tan alto, pero es una forma muy efectiva de evitar que se explote el sistema por los spammers. Si te mantienes activo, verás que al final ganar esa reputación no es tan difícil. Bienvenido a StackOverflow.